# Meteor: Why my template helper isn't reactive?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I want to get path in order to set active class for active tabs. The code works, if I click "refresh" everytime.

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
Template.header.helpers({
    isCurrentPage: function(pageName){
        var pathArr = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        var firstLevelPath = pathArr[1];
        return firstLevelPath == pageName
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li role="presentation" class="{{#if isCurrentPage 'browse'}}active{{/if}}"><a href="{{pathFor 'browse'}}">Browse</a></li>
```

**Full repo**

https://github.com/mvaisanen/flashcards

Comment: Iron.current() holds paths and is reactive, try with that

Comment: This is one of the many reasons to use Iron Router when creating Meteor applications. Unless it's important that your application does NOT behave like a single page application, though I think that's a pretty rare edge case. `meteor add iron:router` [Here are the docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Iron.Location.get().path` returns actual path and is reactive, so I guess you could use this

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm. Btw `Router.current().route.path(this);` might also be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The window object is not reactive then the template does not know about the change. Try to use Tracker.autorun around it to have a reactive behavior.

Check this link that contains more about Tracker

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun